# Get DB2 Constraints list

Tags: sql, database, db2

***For Unique index*** (which enforces unique constraint on the column)

Format:

```
TableName  ColumnName  ConstraintName

Table1  Column1  Const1

Table1  Column2  Const1
```

***For Foreign key constraint***

Format:

```
ConstraintName RefdTableName RefdColumn RefgTableName  RefgColumn
```

**Note:**

```
RefdTableName: ReferencedTableName

RefdColumn: ReferencedColumnName

RefgTableName: ReferencingTableName

RefgColumn: ReferencingColumnName
```

Comment: What is the question, what is your SQL query you have problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Db2 System Catalog

For Indexes the documentation can be found under [SYSCAT.INDEXES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001047.html)

For Foreign Key constraints check out [SYSCAT.REFERENCES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001057.html)